# Remove empty DataFrames from pandas resample object

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions, resampling

I have a pandas DataFrame df with time lapses which may be longer than 30 minutes.
I wish to resample it

```
r = df.resample('30T')
```

and then to apply some aggregation:

```
r.apply(my_fancy_aggregation)
```

my_fancy_aggregation can NOT work on empty array_likes.

How do I clean r from the empty aggregates BEFORE applying my_fancy_aggregation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can filter by `empty`:

```
def my_fancy_aggregation(x):
    if not x.empty:
        return x.sum()

a = r.apply(my_fancy_aggregation)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it'll solves

```
r.dropna(subset=['30T'], how='all')
```